# Check if a single bit is zero

Tags: binary

It's easy to check if a single bit in variable is 1.
Ex. check if the third bit of variable is 1, just do

```
variable & 0100 ==0100
```

How to check if a single bit is 0?

Comment: Simply replace the right-hand side of the `==` operator with zero.  That will tell you that none of the bits `&`'d with `variable` were set, i.e., they were all zero.

Answer (score 1):

say you want to check the second bit is 0

targetBit = 0010

```
(~( variable) & targetBit ) == targetBit
```